# Elementor CSS issue with Membership plugin

Tags: css, display, elementor

I'm having an issue that's a glitch in integration with Elementor and the Skyverge membership plugin. On the member side of the site, the products look normal:
[Normal view of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnZZE.jpg)

However, the site looks terrible when not logged in.
The page is here: https://developmenthandicraftcluborg.bigscoots-staging.com/classes/ (this site hasn't launched yet, so you need to enter "dev" and "dev" into username and password to see the site.

According to Skyverge, unchecking the "display: grid" from Elementor, as shown below, resolved the issue on their end. They suggested reaching out to Elementor for help with the CSS, but they are glacially slow getting around to helping me.

I'm wondering if anyone can help me out with CSS to accomplish this? I'm trying to get the site launched and that page looking horrible is a huge issue.

Thanks in advance!